# Question filter tags are overflowing

Tags: bug, google-chrome, design, internet-explorer

The buttons in the picture below should not be overflowing in to the '*Featured on Meta*' box as they are.

**URL:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php

**OS:** Windows 10

**Browser:** Chrome (69.0.3497.92 (Official Build) (64-bit))

[image]

Comment: Windows 7 and IE11 is also doing this.

Comment: You probably need to have [custom questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313940/289905) disabled to reproduce this.

Comment: I think this was a bug back when they introduced the new layout then they fixed it. They must have accidentally reinstated the same bug with the lastest change.

Comment: @DavyM I read '*reinstated*' as '*reinstalled*' and thought '*That is a new way to describe new bugs*'.

Comment: No repro on MAC High Sierra 10.13.4 using FF 62.0 (on any zoom level)

Comment: How do you even get to see the question count? I've been waiting for that since the new layout and still cannot see it when looking at a tag

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I see the question count when following the link to [tag:php], and I got approximately the same reputation as you, so it's not a privilege issue.

Comment: @Cœur Still cannot see it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPgVb.png

Comment: Isn't this site named Stack **Overflow**? :)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It could be A/B-testing ([it's apparently trendy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374231/why-have-the-week-month-tabs-been-removed)), or related to different [Preferences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/). Mine are currently: *Disable top bar stickiness* and *Hide left navigation*, the rest is unchecked.