# Why have the week/month tabs been removed?

Tags: discussion, design

These were my preferred means for browsing questions and answers - why were they removed (and was this discussed anywhere?)

SO Screenshot:
[image: StackOverflow]

Software Engineering:
[image: Software Engineering]

EDIT: It seems that if I visit in incognito mode they are shown. I'm not opted into any betas as far as I can tell.

FURTHER EDIT: If I visit the "Bounties" tab (it's still labelled as Featured Questions when I get there) the old tabs are shown. They don't work though - visiting the week/month tab just gives me the same view I get on the homepage.

[image: From the Bounties page]

Comment: On which specific page were these tabs? What do you see instead?

Comment: On the Home Page, I see Interesting / Featured / Hot / Week / Month.

Comment: I actually do see “`interesting` `featured` `hot` `week` `month`” on [the home page of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). I can’t reproduce the view in the screenshot (this possibly requires not being opted into [custom questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313940/289905)). But I’m usually never on the Home page anyway. Try the Questions page by clicking on “ Stack Overflow”. If you’re opted into the feature I mentioned, you’ll see a Filter which has Week and Month options.

Comment: @Xufox nope - under the questions page the tabs are Newest/Featured/Frequent/Votes/Active/Unanswered (that hasn't changed as far as I'm aware, just the list on Home)

Comment: @ChrisCooper The questions page only has different navigation if you’re opted into custom questions list, as I described in my comment.

Comment: I don't have Custom Question Lists enabled in my profile. I have not changed anything, it only started displaying like this today.

Comment: It might be an A/B test to see what tabs are best... Hard to say.

Comment: The tabs have reappeared for me today, and the new links are gone - very mysterious

Comment: @ChrisCooper Looks like a definite A/B test then; those are not really announced and users are not notified of whether they will be affected by it (that would skew the results potentially) nor is there a way to avoid it short of browsing while logged out.

Comment: It is for a A/B test.